# How to have multiple tables with multiple joins

Tags: sql, join, firebird

I have three tables that I need to join together and get a combination of results. I have tried using left/right joins but they don't give the desired results.

For example:

Table 1 - STAFF

```
id      name
1       John
2       Fred
```

Table 2 - STAFFMOBILERIGHTS

```
id      staffid     mobilerightsid      rights
--this table is empty--
```

Table 3 - MOBILERIGHTS

```
id      rightname
1       Login
2       View
```

and what I need is this as the result...

```
id  name    id  staffid mobilerightsid  rights  id  rightname
1   John    null    null    null        null    1   login
1   John    null    null    null        null    2   View
2   Fred    null    null    null        null    1   login
2   Fred    null    null    null        null    2   View
```

I have tried the following :

```
SELECT *
  FROM STAFFMOBILERIGHTS SMR
  RIGHT JOIN STAFF STA
  ON STA.STAFFID = SMR.STAFFID
  RIGHT JOIN MOBILERIGHTS MRI
  ON MRI.ID = SMR.MOBILERIGHTSID
```

But this only returns two rows as follows:

```
id      name    id  staffid mobilerightsid  rights  id  rightname
null    null    null    null    null        null    1   login
null    null    null    null    null        null    2   View
```

Can what I am trying to achieve be done and if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment its now clear you want a [cross join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx) (include all rows from staff and mobilerights). Something like this should do it

```
SELECT 
*
FROM Staff, MobileRights
LEFT OUTER JOIN StaffMobileRights ON StaffMobileRights.StaffId = Staff.Id
```

The FROM clause specifies that we will be including all rows from the Staff table, and all rows from the MobileRights table. The end result will therefore contain (staff * MobileRights) rows.

To bring in rows from StaffMobileRights then we need a join to that table also.  We use a LEFT OUTER join to ensure that we always include the left side (rows in the staff table) but we arent too bothered if no rows exist on the right side (StaffMobileRights table). If no row exists for the join then null values are returned.

Comment: Yes STAFFMOBILERIGHTS effectively allows a many-to-many relationship between STAFF and MOBILERIGHTS but there will only be a row in STAFFMOBILERIGHTS if a right has been granted. Right now no rights have been granted so there are no row ins STAFFMOBILERIGHTS.

Running your SQL returns zero rows.

Comment: @williamsdb. Ahh, sorry yes - much clearer what you're trying to do now. See my edit.

Comment: Bingo!

Thanks very much that's perfect. Now I am off to see if I can understand what you have done.

Thanks for your help.

Neil

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably asking is to see null where is no rights. In the rectangular style that results are always returned, this is the only way to represent it with a simple join:

From PaulG's query i changed it a bit to always get everything form the STAFF table.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM STAFF
RIGHT OUTER JOIN StaffMobileRights ON StaffMobileRights.StaffId = Staff.Id
INNER JOIN MobileRights ON MobileRights.Id = StaffMobileRights.MobileRightsId
```